# Convert API color value ("#1db8ce" OR "White") to Actual RGB color

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I can successfully Convert API color value if the  API response in HEx code `"ProductColor": "#20d6ee"` which I convert in real color in my App following way:

```
 color: Color( int?.parse(colorListListVar.productColor.replaceAll('#','0xff') ?? "",), ),
```

where `colorListListVar.productColor` my API response value.

But some API Color value in Hard Coded color(White,Black .etc) . Which is causing my App crashes.
How can I also show the real color if Color value `WHITE` / `BLACK` in response

API RESPONSE:

```
{
"Status": 1,
"Message": "",
"ProductList": [
    {
        "CategoryId": "11",
        "CategoryName": "FURNITURES",
        "SubCategoryId": "38",
        "SubCategoryName": "Lamp Shades",
        "ColorList": [
            {
                "ProductId": "10363",
                "ProductColor": "#20d6ee"
            }
        ]
    },
  
  
    {
        "CategoryId": "11",
        "CategoryName": "FURNITURES",
        "SubCategoryId": "38",
        "SubCategoryName": "Lamp Shades",
        "ColorList": [
            {
                "ProductId": "10362",
                "ProductColor": "WHITE"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

}

UI CODE:

```
child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          for (var colorListListVar in snapshot.data.productList[index].colorList)
                                            Container(
                                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 2),
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(getProportionateScreenWidth(8)),
                                              height:getProportionateScreenWidth(40),
                                              width:getProportionateScreenWidth(40),
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                                //border: Border.all(color: kPrimaryColor),
                                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                              ),
                                              child: DecoratedBox(
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Color( int?.parse(colorListListVar.productColor.replaceAll('#','0xff') ?? "",), ),
                                                  shape:BoxShape.circle,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          Spacer(),
                                        ],
                                      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for this I'll suggest you to ask your backend developer to put `single(hex)` format response not `color name` but for this scenario you can check them using `if else` or `ternary operator`

```
if(colorListListVar.productColor == "white") {
return Colors.white
}

colorListListVar.productColor == "white" ? Colors.white : Color( int?.parse(colorListListVar.productColor.replaceAll('#','0xff') ?? "",), )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a Color object with that hex values for instance for the value "#20d6ee" you can do  `Color(0xff20d6ee)`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand `color:  Color( int?.parse(colorListListVar.productColor.replaceAll('#','0xff') ?? "",), ),`  thats how  I'm gettting `Color(0xff20d6ee) `  But what to do if Color = White in my API response?  Do I need to put in if-else block{} ?

Comment: You can create a Map such as final colorNames = {"WHITE": 0xFFFFFF, "BLACK": 0x000000}  and just before using the colors check if the value is in the colorNames map and if so use the value instead of the key